# Is it possible to set/manipulate vertex colors from geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-colors

Is there a way to output floats or colors into a vertex color layer from geometry nodes in Blender 3.0 or 3.1? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can. Example:

I use the position to create a color (red, if z > .5)

[image]

[image]

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: I was sure that the Output Name in the node properties is the name of the attribute. And seeing in your images Value vs Col I realized the issue was that the Modifier List addon I am using does not show the Output Attributes in the modifier pannel. Once disabled that addon everything fell into place. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome