# How can I get vertex color on geometry generated with geometry nodes

Tags: export, vertices, geometry-nodes, vertex-colors

I am trying to set the vertex color of a generated geometry to output it to a .ply file (and not necessarily having them displayed into the viewport). I can set the vertex color to the original mesh, but not to any generated vertices.

I have done a [minimal example](https://pasteall.org/media/1/b/1b23f16550490c8d26866915591f771d.blend) to show what I mean:
If I switch to the original geometry the vertex colors are correctly set (the original cube appears in pink and the .ply file contains the vertex colors). When I switch to the generated cube, the vertex colors are ignored and not exported.

[image: Geo node with a capture attribute of vertex color showing a white cube that should be blue]

I have followed most of the answers I have found on this StackExchange without success:

- [How to output to vertex color](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/256642/how-to-output-to-a-vertex-color-on-a-geometry-nodes-generated-mesh/256648#256648?newreg=213b4072426648a0b117c8b118b2721f)
- [is-it-possible-to-set-manipulate-vertex-colors-from-geometry-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250110/is-it-possible-to-set-manipulate-vertex-colors-from-geometry-nodes)
- ...

I am on Macos X monterey, with *Blender 3.2.0* alpha Silicon version.

Any ideas on how to properly export vertex colors, or what I am missing?

Comment: i doubt that this is possible. The problem is, that you defined the vertex color on your "original mesh". The newly created mesh doesn't have any vertex color (as i understand it) and so you will never "see" anything. So we need something like a "add vertex color to mesh"-node...but maybe some GN wizards know it better... ;)

Comment: this might be the cause...https://developer.blender.org/T94428

Comment: @Chris, the Col is correctly linked to the vertex corner, just not taken into account..., Although the bug you mentionned seems to be the cause..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Blender 3.2** you can store custom attributes with the node `Store Named Attribute` in any geometry, both existing geometry and geometry created in *Geometry Nodes*.

If, on the other hand, you only use the node `Capture Attribute`, no data will be permanently stored in the geometry, but will only be available if it is referenced somewhere else (for example somewhere else in the node tree or in the shader, if you provide them via a group output.).

The solution for your example looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Any way to see the colors in solid mode? If I set the colors to "attribute", it's black. If I switch the mode to material preview and back to solid mode, it's proper until geonode recalculates and it's all black again. :(

Comment: In 4.0 you can see the colors in solid mode if you name the attribute to the same name as your active color attribute on the original object and then set to show attributes in the shading drop down.